# Has anyone successfully received their free key to Media Center in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center

I read somewhere you can get a free Media Center key here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs

Has anyone actually successfully received their key? I requested one on Friday and have not heard anything back. It says 24 hours, but it doesnt seem to have gone through unless they do not send out keys on weekends or something. Has anyone had the same experience? Is there some requirement that you have to request it while your already in a version of Windows 8/requesting it from IE10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it took 24 hours or more on my hotmail account to get it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got mine, and like @Moab, it did take the full 24 hours. But it also went to my junk mail, so if it has been 24 hours, check your junk mail.